# Changing p tag content outside the html editor

Tags: php, jquery, html

My website needs updates in text every 2-3 days...the problem is that I've made the site 2 years ago, and it's static, meaning pure old school html. I have 4 pages across the site and I have 4 blocks of identical text on each page. What I want to know is what's the quickest way to make that paragraph changeable outside the html editor?

At the moment the only method I'm using is;

- open all 4 pages
- edit 1 paragraph
- paste it on the rest of the pages

It seems pretty neanderthal way of doing things, so I'm listening to any of the advice to improve this.

```
<div id="one">
<p class "text">Red</p>
</div>
```

I'm sure I could come up with some php way for doing this...but is there another way to change the p text tag "red" text with whatever I want?

Thanks people :)

Comment: Without getting too crazy, you could just write your text in a php file (say, myText.php), and then do a PHP include inside of your p tags: <?php include_once("/path/to/myText.php"); ?>

Answer (score 3):

Put those texts into one html file e.g. info.html and then at your page you will just add
`<?php include('info.html'); ?>`

Comment: That means that he has to rename his `.html` files to `.php` or any other extension that will run through the php processor (eg. `.phtml` on some systems). Also a rewrite-rule to rewrite these old URLs to new ones (eg. replace `.html` with `.php`) would be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using the PHP [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.

`index.php`

```
<div id="one">
    <p class="text"><?php echo file_get_contents('text.txt'); ?></p>
</div>
```

`text.txt`

```
Red
```

**EDIT**

Or if you want to use jQuery, you could use its [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

`index.html`

```
<script>
$('.text').load('text.txt');
</script>
<div id="one">
    <p class="text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to get the php get working.....however I need an alternative to php method...I suppose these techniques aren't available with jquery or something similar? Because I'll have change my extension to php and it'll render my backlinks useless

Comment: Got it working. The only thing I noticed now it breaks the href's inside the p. <p class="text"><a href="#"></a></p> doesn't link.

Comment: Try making the file `text.html` rather than `text.txt` to see if that helps

Comment: @user1429247 Don't use jQuery for that as google won't parse these contents. Does your system allow mod_rewrite via .htaccess? Should be possible on most apache servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the contents of an external file by using PHP, like this:

```
<div id="one">
<p class "text"><?php include('myContent.html'); ?></p>
</div>
```

But in order for this to work, you need to change the ending of your `.html` file to `.php`. This can be a problem with existing links to your site or links within your site.

To fix that, place a `.htaccess` file with the following content in your webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will convert all `.html` endings to `.php` under the hood. So if your URL is: `mypage.html`, it will use `mypage.php`.

It will always look for a file with the same name but a `.php` extension, *as long as there's no `.html` file with that name*! So if `mypage.html` actually exists, the rule doesn't apply and it will simply serve you `mypage.html` (that's what the `RewriteCond` is for). That ensures that you can have actual `.html` files next to `.php` files and both can be accessed via `.html` extension in the URL.